# Remove items from a list based on another list

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0

I have two lists of type SelectListItem.
I am trying remove the items in a list which exists in another list.
i tried all type of code but in vain please help me
The codes i tried are:

```
Channels=New List<SelectListItem>();
RequestedChannels=New List<SelectListItem>();
Channels = GetChannelList();
RequestedChannels = GetChannelList(UserID, ControlChannels);
```

1st case

```
Channels = Channels.Except(RequestedChannels).ToList();
```

2nd case

```
Channels = Channels.Where(item => !RequestedChannels.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

3rd case

```
foreach (SelectListItem item in RequestedChannels)
                Channels.Remove(item);
```

But these cases are not working.
Please help.
Thanks and Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override Equals and GetHashCode for the Except and Contains methods to work

> To compare custom data types, implement the IEquatable(Of T) generic
>   interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the
>   type. The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare
>   values of types that implement IEquatable(Of T).

See [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) for details